# How to generate random colors in Java?

Tags: java, swing, colors, jlabel

I would like to generate a random color for `JLabel` in Java. The `JLabel` will be changing the  background every 100 ms and the background has to be random. How to do this?

I thought of using `javax.swing.Timer` class to do this. See, i am stumped.I am not even getting a background when i have tried the `label.setBackground(Color.CYAN)`

```
JLabel l=new JLabel("Label");
Timer t=new Timer(2,new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
  {
       // what is the code here?
  }
});
```

Comment: Please search before you post!

Comment: @JavaTechnical I searched but i didn't find it!

Comment: What were the search terms?  I suggest SO for '[java] color random'.

Comment: Use [tag] to search, try using different keywords as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `java.util.Random` class and the constructor,

> I am not even getting a background when i have tried the
>   label.setBackground(Color.CYAN)

This is because the `label` is not opaque. Make it opaque for the background to be visible.

```
final JLabel label=new JLabel("Label");
        // Label must be opaque to display
        // the background
        label.setOpaque(true);

        final Random r=new Random();
        Timer t=new Timer(100,new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
            {
                Color c=new Color(r.nextInt(256),r.nextInt(256),r.nextInt(256),r.nextInt(256));
                label.setBackground(c);
            }
        });
        t.start();
```

You can use any of the constructors in the the [Color](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html) class. For generating `float` values you can use `Math.random()` or `r.nextFloat()`

Comment: It is not compiling! :(

Comment: Why? What is the error?

Comment: I am getting reference to Timer is ambiguous

Comment: Import the correct `Timer`  !

Comment: Both `java.util` and `javax.swing` contain Timer class, for using `Random` class just write `import java.util.Random;` it has to work.

Comment: @SayOff Just to be clear, the correct `Timer` to import is `javax.swing.Timer`.

Comment: @JavaTechnical Just wanted to point out, for correctness, that you should replace `255` with `256`, since `nextInt()` returns a *«value between 0 (inclusive) and the specified value (exclusive)»*. `Color` accepts integers from 0 to 255 inclusive.

Comment: I replaced it before you have commented! First :)! Thanks anyways! +1

Answer (score 11):

If I were, I would only randomize the hue component, not the brightness, not the saturation.

```
double hue = Math.random();
int rgb = Color.HSBtoRGB(hue,0.5,0.5);
Color color = new Color(rgb);
```

It will be much more pretty.